# If I use a div wrap element to center my whole website, it loses it's responsiveness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I made a nice website. At the end I wanted to center it and make some ad space on the sides, so I used this:

```
#wrap { 
width: 1200px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

My website was fully mobile responsive, the navbar turned into a buttton and the post gradually got more stacked as opposed to being in a grid (it's sort of like a news/magazine type of thing)

How would I go about centering it while keeping it responsive, to make it look better/make ad space on the sides?

Comment: Share an example code or a fiddle when you ask a question. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Responsive means adapting the dimensions of the webpage to the viewport dimensions. How can the webpage be responsive when you explicitly set how wide the page is going to be.

Comment: I copied the exact wrap css code from a website when I was looking how to globally center everything. I didn't think everything through and I know I look like an idiot but I literally started learning html and css from scratch 3-4 days ago (I do have a web design class at school but so far we only did frames etc. which are sort of useless)

Answer (score 1):

Try width 100% and height 100% instead of fixed pixels

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) as by using width you are stating that it is always 1200px wide (regardless of the device width).

> The max-width property is used to set the maximum width of a given
>   element. It prevents the used value of the width property from
>   becoming larger than the value specified for max-width.

Answer (score 0):

If you put fixed pixels, this size won't vary when the screen size shrinks. You can try adding media queries that change that fixed width. For example:

```
//for screens smaller than 600px, adapt the width to the full width of the screen
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #wrap { 
        width: 100%; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering

I really dont want to bother the comunnity again by asking another question but I wanted to ask you directly how do I get the @ media think to work, do I still leave the one with only #wrap there or do I need to do @ media for every device?
Because I used that and made it 80% in the one without @ media and then I added a @ media for phones and another for tables and set the width to 100% but it still shrinks it to 80% on my phone..

Comment: Yes, you should add a `@media` for every device you need. Be careful because the order you put this media queries affect the outcome. Maybe what's happening to you is that the last media query entered is overwriting the styles in the other ones. Try to order them by screen size so that one particular size only enters one media query at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving % instead of using px to width.

> #wrap { width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; }